# How to check if "Ask for push notifications" permission alert has been clicked on

Tags: ios, push-notification

How to check if and when the user makes an action on this view?

I want to do this:

```
if notificationviewclosed{
    dosomething
}
```

However I couldn't figure out a decent way to check this. Here is my code:

```
func SetupPushNotifications(){

    // Register for Push Notitications
    var userNotificationTypes:UIUserNotificationType = (UIUserNotificationType.Alert |
        UIUserNotificationType.Badge |
        UIUserNotificationType.Sound)

    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().respondsToSelector("isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications"){ //this should be done with getobjc method
        // iOS 8 Notifications
        var settings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }else{
        // iOS < 8 Notifications
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(.Badge | .Sound | .Alert)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle the users response to the prompt by implementing both of the following methods in your AppDelegate.

**For iOS8:**

```
     func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings)
```

**For < iOS8:**

```
     func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData)
```

In this method you can check if the user has given permission by calling the following and checking the value

```
application.enabledRemoteNotificationTypes()
```

See here for more info:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings

Comment: i dont really trust the simulator so, does this part get called again if the user is already registered? or is it only for the first time? by registered i mean SetupPushNotifications executed positively before

Comment: In my experience it will get called for each subsequent call to registerUserNotificationSettings()

Comment: This will only work the first time you open the app on each device, even if you reinstall it. There are however some hacky ways to repeatingly show the subscription alert, including resetting date & time.

Comment: @boeqqsh I think you may have misread the question. Esq wasn't asking how to prompt for permission, but rather handle the response if/ when given. At least that was my take.

Comment: Yeah, and you'll only get a response when the prompt is being shown (as far as I experienced this).